# Microsoft Bot Framework :turncontext

Tags: botframework

I am new to Microsoft bot framework and have seen the term turncontext many times.

Can some one explain what that actually means and its significance.

eg: turncontext(adapter,activity)

Answer (score 4):

When using a bot, the user and the bot take it in turns to speak. Within the Bot framework a turn is a users incoming activity which the bot responds too. Every message a bot receives from a new user will be in a new turn.

If the user asks a question "What is the weather like today?", the bot may respond with "Where would you like the weather for?". That is all in one turn. The user then responds with "London", this is in a new turn.

The turnContext is the object that gives you access to the information about the current turn from the user. This includes the current message sent by the user among for example. For a full specification see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontext?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). It's also used to send messages back to the user, SendActivityAsync is one to do this.

Take a look at this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) I used as the basic of this answer which goes into way more detail. Also take a look through the [Bot Framework Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) and step through the code to learn more about the turnContext.

Comment: @Nithin is this an acceptable answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

When building a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework, it is essential to understand the concept of a *TurnContext*. In simple terms, the TurnContext represents a single back-and-forth conversation between the user and the bot. Each time a user sends a message to the bot, it is considered a new turn.

A turn has **two main components**: the **user's incoming activity** and the **bot's outgoing activity**. The user's incoming activity can take many forms, such as *text messages*, *button clicks*, or *requests* for information. The bot's outgoing activity is its response to the user, which can be anything from *simple text messages* to *rich cards*.

You can use the *activity* object to access important information about the turn, such as **message text**, **sender**, **recipient**, and **timestamp**. It contains all the details you need to handle the user's request and respond appropriately. By understanding the TurnContext and the components of a turn, you can build more effective and engaging bots that meet the needs of your users.

```
// Example of accessing activity properties in TurnContext
var userMessage = turnContext.Activity.Text;
var sender = turnContext.Activity.From;
var recipient = turnContext.Activity.Recipient;
```

The TurnContext is a crucial component in **managing a conversation's context**. It provides the necessary information about the user, channel, and ongoing conversation, enabling the bot to comprehend the user's intent and maintain continuity throughout multiple turns. This context management capability is essential in enabling the bot to maintain its state across the conversation, ensuring seamless interactions with the user.

To better understand, you can review the code snippets below.

```
public async Task ProcessUserMessageAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var customUserState = turnContext.TurnState.Get<UserState>();
    var userStateAccessor = customUserState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>("UserProfileData");

    var userProfileData = await userStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var incomingMessage = turnContext.Activity.Text;
        var userIntent = RecognizeUserIntent(incomingMessage);

        UpdateUserProfileData(userProfileData, userIntent);

        var botResponse = GenerateBotResponse(userProfileData);

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(botResponse), cancellationToken);
    }
}

private string RecognizeUserIntent(string userMessage)
{
    // Your custom logic for recognizing user intent, such as using NLP or predefined patterns.
    return "GeneralGreetingIntent"; // Example: Assume the user greeted the bot
}

private void UpdateUserProfileData(UserProfile userProfileData, string detectedIntent)
{
    // Your custom logic for updating user profile data based on the detected intent.
    // This might involve maintaining counters, preferences, or other user-specific information.
    userProfileData.LastDetectedIntent = detectedIntent;
}

private string GenerateBotResponse(UserProfile userProfileData)
{
    // Your custom logic for generating a bot response based on user profile data.
    // This might involve customizing the response according to the user's preferences or history.
    return $"Hello {userProfileData.UserName}! It seems you're interested in {userProfileData.LastDetectedIntent}. How can I assist you further?";
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public string UserName { get; set; } = "Valued User";
    public string LastDetectedIntent { get; set; } = "UnknownIntent";
}
```

**TL;DR:**

One of the fundamental concepts in Microsoft Bot Framework is the TurnContext, which facilitates communication between a user and a bot.

- It represents a single turn in the conversation between the user and the bot.
- TurnContext carries essential information about the ongoing conversation, user, and channel.
- It enables the bot to manage conversation and user-specific state, facilitating a more personalized and coherent interaction.
- TurnContext is instrumental in processing and interpreting the incoming Activity, allowing the bot to generate relevant and context-aware responses.

Answer (score -1):

In the Microsoft Bot Framework, TurnContext is a fundamental concept used to manage and track the context of a conversation between a bot and a user. It represents the context of a single turn or interaction within a conversation. A turn typically includes a user's message or input and the bot's response.

Turn Context is an object that encapsulates information about the current turn, including:

Activity: The user's message or activity that triggered the current turn. This includes the user's message text, channel-specific information, and more.

BotAdapter: The adapter responsible for processing the incoming activity and sending outgoing activities. It's the communication bridge between your bot and the messaging platform.

Bot: A reference to the bot logic itself, which allows you to access the bot's methods and properties.

ConversationReference: Information about the conversation, such as the conversation ID, user ID, and channel ID. This is useful for storing context or sending proactive messages.

Services: A collection of services that the bot can use to interact with external resources or APIs. This can include services for state management, authentication, and more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).